# Right min/max values in single band color of an asc file and resulted profile

Tags: qgis, esri-ascii-raster, profile

I'm using some asc files that covered the surface of an island; every file, when it's been imported, has a different min/max values in the single band color, which is the right? How can I understand it? I think it isn't normal that colors changes like in the following image in two subsequent images

[image]

Then I have another problem. I get the profile with differnt tool, but in any case the result is different (20 m) from the profile got from google earth... can it depend from the band colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single band gray rasters are usually imported into QGIS with min and max values at 2% and 98% of the data range.

If you want several neighbouring rasters to appear in the same grayscale, you have to set the min and max values of all layers manually to the same values in the `Style` tab of the properties.

Alternatively, you can use `Styles -> Copy Style` and `-> Paste Style` to apply the same style to all layers.

For the second question: You can not be sure about Google's data source for elevation. If you have elevation data from local surveying authorities, you can trust them more.

Comment: I knew it and I did it, but the difference between my profile and the one from google earth make me though that difference comes from the single band. Thank you so much!